# Unable to select android emulator in Xamarin VS

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator, visual-studio-emulator, xamarin-android-player

I'm using Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 Edition (Update 3), with Xamarin 4.2 installed.
I have the emulators downloaded via Xamarin Android Player, however I don't have an option to select the emulators from Visual Studio (Refer attached image).
[VS Select Emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeAjH.jpg)

There is no emulator dropdown next to debug button in toolbar, and VS always defaults to the first emulator, and doesn't let me choose one, even if there are multiple emulators available in XAP.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Xamarin Android Player is not longer supported

Comment: Thanks for your response. 
Unfortunately, uninstalling XAP doesn't help as well, since I still don't have the ability to select emulators in VS.
I've even created multiple AVDs using Android Emulator Manager, but VS automatically deploys to the first AVD, without providing me an option to select a target AVD.
I had the ability to select my choice of target device earlier, by selecting it from the drop down list on debug button, but that seems to have disappeared after the last update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying to figure out the problem for days, I was finally able to identify the real cause of the issue. I had to enable Standard toolbar in VS (Right-click on Toolbar, and select Standard. [Refer Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9xXG.jpg)) to finally have the ability to select emulators.

I was under the assumption that the emulator list appears in Debug toolbar, and did not try checking the toolbar menu earlier.

Thanks for all the replies, and hope this helps someone else facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be this bug:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44487

If so, the issue occurs when selecting the startup project with the drop down list in the tool bar. Instead try selecting the start up project by right-clicking on the project on the Solution Explorer and choose "Set as startup project"

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, in my case this isn't the issue, as the project is set as Startup Project already.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't select the startup project. In Solution Explorer right click on your Android project and choose "Set as StartUp Project". Then default emulator options should be visible and you can change it via drop down menu.

Anyway I recomend you to use [Visual Studio emulator](https://www.visualstudio.com/vs/msft-android-emulator/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've already set the project as Startup project, to no avail. I'm using Win 7, and hence cannot install VS Emulator.